# How to update rails version from 2.3.14 to 3.2.11?

Tags: updates, versions, rails

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and I need to update Rails version or need to reinstall the latest version but in vain.

I've tried to install rails (`sudo gem install rails`), showing:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: **Failed to build gem native extension**.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in **`require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)**
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Where to go from here? I am not able to remove rails because of installing rails with sudo command.

Comment: *"I am using ruby 1.9.3"* The output shows you're running `1.9.1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror) on StackOverflow you just need to install the `-dev` package of your Ruby version installed, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

And then re-run the gem installation.